# PHP - Accessing and sending data to process

Tags: php, cross-process

I've been programming a small client-server-application and now I want to show the output of the server-process in a small server-webpage. Everytime, you press a key in the server-console, the current state is output. Assuming, the server is running and I want to show the current state of the server, how would you implement this in PHP?

My thoughts were to get the process and then send a key input. How could you implement this in PHP? The server is running on debian 6 with Apache and PHP 5.4.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use extJS and Node.JS for the same I think so

Comment: Where does the output stream of your server-console process go?

Comment: node.js seems not to work, because I want to view the page on different devices, even from outside my network (port-forwarding enabled)

The server outputs directly to the console it was started from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depend on how simple you want to go:

the simplest would be to just simulate a get call. for example, the client calls **fopen('http://server.example.com/status.php?server=myserver&stats=uptime');** and at the server level, look at $_GET['server'] and $_GET['uptime'] . you can use that method and add authentication either by passing credentials as a variable. The output can be either plain html or json encoded

use xml rpc or soap

Comment: - That's my main problem. I want to display this data with the information I got from the console. I understood your answer like this: update these states every (e.g.) 5 seconds into a file and display these states in my PHP-page


- How would you implement the second one?

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do but 2 options:
(1) update a file with a cron job
(2) execute the command to get that information with backticks. For example, for uptime, use $uptimeResult=`uptime`;

Comment: not sure why the backticks are removed, it is the character like a quote by slanted on the top left of qwerty keyboards - it executes the command and puts the result in the variable

Comment: I think we're talking past each other. The process is already running and I want to interact with this running one, not start a new one. But I think you're right, updating an external file would be simpler than digging into the processes. Thanks anyway!